# Django manager with parameters

Tags: django

I want to create a Manager in DJango that filters on id and sensor.
This is my manager:

```
class BrokenDeviceManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self, device_id, sensor):
        return (
            super()
            .get_queryset()
            .filter(brokensensor__exact=device_id, brokensensor__sensor=sensor,)
        )
```

When trying this in a test class:

```
Device.broken_objects.filter(
            device_id=device.id, sensor=Sensor.COUGHS
        ).count()
```

It gives me:

```
TypeError: get_queryset() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'device_id' and 'sensor'
```

Also tried other approaches, without succes..
This is the brokensensor class:

```
class BrokenSensor(models.Model):
    sensor = models.PositiveIntegerField(choices=Sensor.choices())
    device = models.ForeignKey(
        Device, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="brokensensor"
    )

    def __str__(self):  # pragma: no cover
        return "pk{} - device: {} - sensor: {}".format(
            self.pk, self.device_id, self.sensor
        )
```

Comment: It is `get_queryset`, not `get_query_set`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I edited my question with your remarks, thanks

Comment: @codinginquarantaine: well you can not add parameters to `get_queryset`, since that is called when you call `filter`, but *without* the parameters.

Comment: So.. bit confused. Do I need to change my Manager or the "test class"?

Comment: Solved it by doing this:
class BrokenDeviceManager(models.Manager):
    def broken_sensor_check(self, device_id, sensor):
        return (
            super(BrokenDeviceManager, self)
            .get_queryset()
            .filter(brokensensor__exact=device_id, brokensensor__sensor=sensor)
        )

Seems ok?

Answer (score 2):

Looking at your question and the given solution on the comments section of your question:

```
class BrokenDeviceManager(models.Manager):
    def broken_sensor_check(self, device_id, sensor):
        return (
            super(BrokenDeviceManager, self)
            .get_queryset()
            .filter(brokensensor__exact=device_id, brokensensor__sensor=sensor)
        )
```

It seems to do the job, however for that solution I believe a better method would be to use a [`QuerySet`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/managers/#creating-a-manager-with-queryset-methods). It is a simpler interface that extends your chaining methods and allows you to call it in whatever order you're pleased. Also a [`Manager`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/managers/) should work without special methods or parameters, as its idea is to work in backstage and do all the "magic" on it own, normally overriding `get_queryset()`.

So to use a `Queryset` you must first declare one and its methods and then add to your models with `.as_manager()`.

```
class BrokenDeviceQuerySet(models.query.QuerySet):

    def broken_sensor_check(self, device_id, sensor):
        return self.filter(brokensensor__exact=device_id, brokensensor__sensor=sensor)

class Device(models.Model):
    # your fields and stuff
    broken_objects = BrokenDeviceQuerySet.as_manager()
```

The problem I see with your solution is that it does not allow chaining, for example: `Device.broken_objects.all().broken_sensor_check()` can't be done with it.

Answer (score 0):

For those looking for a manager to filter based on a condition, the following was the solution for me:

```
class BrokenDeviceManager(models.Manager):
    has_device = DEFAULT_VALUE

    def __init__(self, has_device, *args, **kwargs):
        self.has_device = has_device
        super().__init__()

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.has_device:
           return super().get_queryset().exclude(device_id=None)
        return super().get_queryset().filter(device_id=None)
```

So you can make two managers on the model such as:

```
class BrokenSensor(models.Model):
    ...

    objects = models.Manager()
    w_device_objects = LayerManager(has_device=True)
    wo_device_objects = LayerManager(has_device=False)
```

And call with

```
BrokenSensor.w_device_objects.all()
BrokenSensor.wo_device_objects.all()
```

This was useful for me because the filter was a cascate of foreign keys, so I could simplify the writing:

```
def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
   qs = super().get_queryset()
   if self.is_db:
      return qs.exclude(history__database_class_str=None)
   return qs.filter(history__database_class_str=None)
```